# Does spark not check UDF / Column type?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Consider the following Spark 2.1 code:

```
val df = Seq("Raphael").toDF("name")
df.show()    

+-------+
|   name|
+-------+
|Raphael|
+-------+

val squareUDF = udf((d:Double) => Math.pow(d,2))

df.select(squareUDF($"name")).show

+---------+
|UDF(name)|
+---------+
|     null|
+---------+
```

Why do I get `null`? I was expecting something like a `ClassCastException` because I try to map a String on a Scala Double

```
"Raphael".asInstanceOf[Double]

java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Double
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is easy to figure out if you check the execution plan:

```
scala> df.select(squareUDF($"name")).explain(true)
== Parsed Logical Plan ==
'Project [UDF('name) AS UDF(name)#51]
+- AnalysisBarrier Project [value#36 AS name#38]

== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
UDF(name): double
Project [if (isnull(cast(name#38 as double))) null else UDF(cast(name#38 as double)) AS UDF(name)#51]
+- Project [value#36 AS name#38]
   +- LocalRelation [value#36]

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
LocalRelation [UDF(name)#51]

== Physical Plan ==
LocalTableScan [UDF(name)#51]
```

As you can see Spark performs type casting before applying UDF:

```
UDF(cast(name#38 as double))
```

and SQL casts does't throw exceptions for type compatible casts. If actual cast is impossible the value is undefined (`NULL`). If types were incompatible:

```
Seq((1, ("Raphael", 42))).toDF("id", "name_number").select(squareUDF($"name_number"))
// org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'UDF(name_number)' due to data type mismatch: argument 1 requires double type, however, '`name_number`' is of struct<_1:string,_2:int> type.;;
// 
// at org.apache...
```

you'd get an exception.

If types where incompatible

The rest is covered by:

```
if (isnull(cast(name#38 as double))) null
```

Since value is `null` udf is never called.

Comment: @Jasper-M Simplicity? a) You have to support up-casting b) You have to support different external representations (for doubles, Java primitive and boxed one, plus Scala one). The biggest problem is that is inconsistent. In some context you get analysis exception, in some match exception, and the rest will behave like this one. But compared to other Spark SQL issues (internationalization anyone), this is a minor issue.